# rendering problems in android studio - com.android.gms.ads.adview

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I'm spending already 2 days to figure what is the problem with this Error.

this is the error in my Activity.xml:

```
rendering problems could not be found com.android.gms.ads.adview
```

and this is what i have in code:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

i followed this guide:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

this is my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
}
```

please Help

Comment: Seems like play service library is not added properly..

Comment: should I reinstall it ?

Comment: Yes. You are using Android studio?

Comment: i did it, and it still not help. 
and yes, i have android studio.

thanks for your fast help

Comment: Go to Dependencies in your project setting. check if play service library is listing there. Problem is causing because  classes in library can not be found.

Comment: i edited my question and added my Dependencies, please take a look

Comment: Dependencies seems correct. You can do couple of things which may solve your problem like updating Play services (Latest version : 7.5.0) and clean your project from Build menu and then rebuild.

Comment: did it already, doesnt help. i did uninstall now, i hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I still encountered this issue while using Firebase.

So I hope it will save some time for you. To fix it:

1. Go to [Firebase official site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and check the latest version. (10.0.1 right now)
2. Update your app gradle file according to this version number, for example:

   `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'`

   `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'`

   `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'`
3. If the gradle doesn't sync / Failed to resolve. Open SDK Manager and update Google Repository for the last version possible.